# How to search for a word in a sentence with LIKE in eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to search for a word in the values of a field so used LIKE but it doesn't give me the output I want.
I wrote this code:

```
 User::where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $search . '%')->get();
```

If the name values are as follows:

```
|-------------------|
|      name         |
|-------------------|
|    John Doe       |
|-------------------|
|    Jane Smith     |
|-------------------|
|    Will Johnson   |
|-------------------|
|    MyJohnTest     |
|-------------------|
|    Sara TestJohn  |
|-------------------|
```

The result of the above code output for **John** is the following values

```
|-------------------|
|      name         |
|-------------------|
|    John Doe       |
|-------------------|
|    Will Johnson   |
|-------------------|
|    MyJohnTest     |
|-------------------|
|    Sara TestJohn  |
|-------------------|
```

But I want to have this output, the query is equal to the first of each word

```
|-------------------|
|      name         |
|-------------------|
|    John Doe       |
|-------------------|
|    Will Johnson   |
|-------------------|
```

Please tell me if you have a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL don't know where your word end so you could use

```
  User::where('name', 'LIKE', $search . ' %')
        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE',' %'. $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE','% '. $search . ' %')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Your code for some situations did not have the correct value in the output, but it gave me the problem solving key, changed the code below, thank you
User::where('name', 'LIKE',$search . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE','% '. $search . '%')
            ->get();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('name', 'like', $search.'%')
                ->get();
```

Comment: This code does not return the value of **Will Johnson**